# Android APK INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED Now Premission Denied

Tags: android, mobile, adb, android-install-apk

I have been working with Monkey Talk and Xamarin Android. With my APK generated by Xamarin the Monkey Talk instrumentation would not work. Yesterday I got it to work by pushing the assemblies to the /data/data/com.app/files/.**override** folder. I hacked around until I got it to work and changed the chmod on some folders, added a folder to /data/data/com.app/ and got it to work.

Today I uninstalled the working build so that I could automated what I had done. After running "adb uninstall com.app" then running the install for the base APK, I keep getting "INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED".

I have seen similar threads suggesting params you can add to the uninstall.

The following did NOT work:

1. adb shell pm clear com.app
2. adb -d install -r com.apk
3. adb shell; rm -r /data/data/com.app (permission denied)
4. (push to sdcard then) adb shell pm install -l /sdcard/tmp/smv.apk
5. redownloading the app from the app store

If this was before I uninstalled I could have used "run-as com.app", but now since the app is no longer I can't get permissions to remove the lingering data folder. "run-as: Package 'com.app' is unknown"

I want to avoid rooting the device. But how in the world can I get rid of the old files? Can I restore the ability to use run-as? I also don't want to reinstall Android ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to reboot your device before reinstalling the app. That worked for me.

Comment: Still getting INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED